# How to implement firebase's signInWithPhoneNumber in express?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express

I wish to implement `signInWithPhoneNumber()` on the backend. That is, Get the phone number and recaptcha on the front, let the backend handle the request to firebase, send the confirmation code from the front with the `confirmationResult` to the backend and verify there.

How do I go about sending the recaptcha to my express backend? `signInWithPhoneNumbers` requires `RecaptchaVerifier` as a second argument, which returns a promise. I can't send it as is, is there a work around for this?

Comment: firebase is a technology meant to be used as a backend and not behind another backend. The documentation of firebase clearly indicates that the javascript sdk is to be used for web front end (https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup). Whereas express js is a backend framework. Answering the question would involve first understanding what you are trying to achieve by moving the firebase access code to the backend

Comment: @vvs The main idea is to abstract firebase behind our api. I am aware that it is intended to work on the client but this isn't my design choice.

Comment: The api you are trying to use is meant for a web based browser or a mobile frontend. So you should revisit the design choice. Else you may end up with a hacky implementation in trying to go with the design choice or have to change the way you authenticate  to use firebase Auth on frontend and pass a token after Auth to the backend. Have a look at these links https://dev.to/emeka/securing-your-express-node-js-api-with-firebase-auth-4b5f

Comment: @vvs Your comments are pretty much it: Firebase SDKs sign the user in from the device where the code runs. You can't sign the user in to a device from back-end code, although you can mint custom tokens from the back-end and use those to sign in with client-side code. Would you mind writing up an answer based on your (and my, if you want) comments, so that I can upvote it?

Comment: @Nix If somebody else made this choice, then consider having *them* ask the question. As it stands it reads like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me: why do you want to sign in to Firebase from backend code (a combination that isn't possible)?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen. Thanks. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase is a technology meant to be used as a backend and not behind another backend. The documentation of firebase clearly indicates that the javascript sdk is to be used for web front end (https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).

Whereas express js is a backend. Given a  design choice of abstracting firebase behind the api, I would suggest you revisit the design choice. As in mentioned in another comment this appears to be a XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).
The api you are trying to use is meant for a web based browser or a mobile frontend. You may end up with a hacky implementation in trying to go with the design choice or have to change the way you authenticate to use firebase Auth on frontend and pass a token after Auth to the backend. Have a look at these links

https://dev.to/emeka/securing-your-express-node-js-api-with-firebase-auth-4b5f
https://fireship.io/snippets/express-middleware-auth-token-firebase/

There is another option of using a custom implementation of authentication backend to generate token and use that token to sign in to firebase. That would however beat the purpose of the firebase Auth. I would recommend it only if you already have a existing backend and are adding firebase for different features of firebase. Please consider this link if that matters to you.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth